# SpTBX: tab control: how to owner-draw tab headers

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

`TSpTbxTabControl`. I need to owner-draw tab headers: a)draw colored line at top of header (misc color), b) draw some colored BG (not only draw themed BG).

I see only `OnDrawBackground` which uses rect for "lower" area(below headers), not rect for tab headers.

[image: draw here]

Answer (score 3):

Need to use `OnDrawItem` for tabs placed on tab control, `TSpTbxTabItem`.
If tabs added at runtime, need to assign all 
`(TabCtl.Toolbar.Items[i] as TSpTbxTabItem).OnDrawItem`.

```
with SpTBXTabControl1.Toolbar do
for i:= 0 to Items.Count-1 do
  (Items[i] as TSpTbxTabItem).OnDrawItem:= SpTBXTabItem1DrawItem;
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to provide a code sample for future readers? It would make for a much better answer.